# Add star ratings to my model rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called *teacher* that I'd like to add ratings to (5 star). Currently, I implement this by adding a *ratings* nested route (resource rating) inside of my teacher resource. Then I created a model: rating with (id, user_id, teacher_id, ratings, ...). Then I created a form with hidden fields, one of which is called *stars*. When a user clicks on a star, I use jQuery to send an AJAX request to create/update the rating for that user and teacher.

My confusion is this: I'm having two separate forms on the page. I have a form for writing the reviewers comments. This form has two fields: title, comments (and submit). Then I have the ratings form with hidden fields. Is this the right way to go about something like this? It seems to me that I should really have the ratings model fields somehow embedded in the main review form.

Any help highly appreciated. Thank you.

[EDIT]

I've updated my application so that instead of rating a **teacher** object, users now rate a **comment** on a **teacher**

my setup is something like this:

*routes*

```rb
resources :comments as :teacher_comments do  
 resource :rating  
end
```

*models*

**comment**

```
has_one :rating  
attr_accessible :body, :rating_attributes  
accepts_nested_attributes_for :rating
```

**rating**

```
belongs_to :comment  
attr_accessible :stars, :user_id, :teacher_id, :comment_id
```

*view*

```
<%= form_for( @comment, :remote => true, :url => teacher_comments_path ) do |tc| %>
  <%= tc.text_area :body, :maxlength => 450  %>
  <%= tc.fields_for :rating do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.text_field :stars  %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I don't see the text_field for the stars. It's just not showing up. Is there something I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, it's generally better to have all these fields in a single form (good for user experience).

**Edit:**

You might use the method `accepts_nested_attributes_for` (as you suggested in the comments below). Put the following in your parent Model (teacher); then you should be able to create a single form to handle inputs for both Models:

in the model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :rating
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :rating
end
```

in the controller:

```
def new
  @comment = Comment.new
  @comment.rating = Rating.new
end
```

Ryan Bates gives a detailed screencast on the use of these concepts here: [Nested Model Form](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1). I recommend it for users who want to know more ins and outs.

**Original:**

This means that you'll need to point the form to an action that can handle both types of input. You can still use `form_for` if you like, but specify an action other than your default (or change the code within the default action in your teacher_controller.rb file):

```
<%= form_for @teacher, :url => {:action => 'create_and_rate'} do |f| %>
```

Since rating is a Model distinct from teacher (whose form we just created), you'll want to use the generic `_tag` form helpers for the rating fields.

```
<%= text_field_tag :rating, :name %> # rating's fields should use the generic form helper
<%= f.text_field :name %> # teacher's fields can use the specific form helper
```

Since you are pointing to a non-RESTful action, add it to your routes file.

```
resources :teacher do
  :collection do
    post 'create_and_rate' # this will match /teachers/create_and_rate to TeachersController#create_and_rate
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This looks like a really clean way. I've kept searching and found that you can also use: **accepts_nested_attributes_for** method in the parent model. I like your solution as it's less magic, but do you know whether using this method in the model is the *rails way* of doing it? Again, thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad to have been of any use. I've no experience with the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` method, so I can't evaluate it very well, but I think I'll use it (instead of my solution) in future. It looks great.

Comment: Hey I've updated my model a bit. You can see in the Edit section above. Now the **accepts_nested_attributes_for** just doesn't seem to work!

Comment: You did a great job, but you need to create a rating in your controller if you aren't already: `@comment.rating = Rating.new` (any different?)